# How to pass value as a argument in send transactions?

Tags: astar, substrate-front-end, javascript, basic-contract-caller

An error occurred: 'Expected 2 arguments for the contract message `'vote'`, but only 1 was provided.First argument was  `number type`, and the second one was `Enum` . This error arises when attempting to pass two values, one being a number and the other a string, which are not accepted by the `Astar chain`.

> I have used it.

```
  const { gasRequired, result } = await contract?.query?.vote(
    {
      gasLimit: gasLimit,
    },
    12892,
    "noDiscrepancies"
  );
  console.log("gasRequired", gasRequired, result);
```

Here is the ABI :

```
"label": "vote",
        "mutates": true,
        "payable": false,
        "returnType": {
          "displayName": [
            "ink",
            "MessageResult"
          ],
          "type": 17
        },
        "selector": "0x083be260"
      },
      {
        "args": [
          {
            "label": "_vote_id",
            "type": {
              "displayName": [
                "u32"
              ],
              "type": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "default": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't seem that the error is a chain related. It will behave the same on any other parachain.

You need to provide origin (caller address) to the call.

```
const { gasRequired, result } = await contract?.query?.vote(
    callerAddress,
    {
      gasLimit: gasLimit,
    },
    12892,
    "noDiscrepancies"
  );
```